# Custom Segue Flashes

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue, uianimation

I am using the following code to override the perform method in a custom segue to achieve sliding effect when moving between view controllers.

```
- (void)perform
{
    MasterController *sourceController = (MasterController *)self.sourceViewController;
    MasterController *destinationController = (MasterController *)self.destinationViewController;

    CGRect frame = sourceController.view.frame;

    [sourceController.view addSubview:destinationController.view];
    [destinationController.view setFrame:CGRectOffset(frame, frame.size.width, 0)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

        [sourceController.view setFrame:CGRectOffset(frame, -frame.size.width, 0)];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [sourceController presentViewController:destinationController animated:NO completion:nil];
        [destinationController.view removeFromSuperview];

    }];
}
```

Similar to this code exists all over the internet. the problem is that "sometimes" after the animation finish the screen flashes/blinks/flickers then gets back normal.

removing `[destinationController.view removeFromSuperview];` line of code seems to solve the problem. but, that doesn't look right! right?

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same issue with a very similar implementation

Comment: I solve it by adding childs view controllers to a one parent view controller. and when I wanna move between controllers, I add the controller I want to move to out of screen. then do the animation then remove the unwanted controller. I am not subclassing segues anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply remove `[destinationController.view removeFromSuperview];`. It will be done for you. At the end of the segue, `destinationController.view` will have a new superview and will be removed from `sourceController.view`.